# SOQL statements cannot query more than 20 different child types error

Tags: apex, governorlimits, sobject, describesobject, sobjecttype

I have the following piece of code

```
 public static void fetchRelatedRecords(String primaryRecordString){
    SObject primaryRecord = (SObject)JSON.deserialize(primaryRecordString, SObject.class);
    String recordId = (String)primaryRecord.get('Id');
    Map<String, Schema.SobjectType> keys = new Map<String, Schema.SobjectType>();
    Map<String, Schema.SobjectType> describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    for(String s : describe.keyset()){
        keys.put(describe.get(s).getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(),describe.get(s));
    }

    Schema.SObjectType sobjectTypeObj = keys.get(recordId.substring(0,3));        
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult obj = sobjectTypeObj.getDescribe();        
    String query = 'select Id, ';
    for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: obj.getChildRelationships()){
        if (cr.getRelationshipName() == null){ 
            continue;
        }
        else{
            system.debug('Child Object Relationship Name:'+cr.getRelationshipName());
            query = query + '(select Id from ' + String.valueOf(cr.getRelationshipName()) + '), '; 
        }
    }
    query = query.removeEnd(', ');
    query = query + ' from ' + String.valueOf(sobjectTypeObj) + ' where Id = ' + '\'' + recordId + '\'';
    List<SObject> relatedRecordList = Database.query(query);
}
```

My problem here is that it is giving me the following error

System.UnexpectedException: SOQL statements cannot query more than 20 different child types.

Is there any way to by pass this governor limit?

Comment: What about making 2 (or n) queries?

Comment: I tried making n queries, but, then I get to a point where I have to do queries within a for loop, which again goes against the best practise. Is there any way to do n queries without a loop? @kurunve

Answer (score 1):

This is a [documented limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm) on SOQL parent-child queries:

> No more than 20 parent-to-child relationships can be specified in a query.

You'll have to batch your queries in groups of 20 parent-child relationships.

Comment: I tried to put it in separate queries, 20 at a time. But a point comes when I have to run the separate queries within a for loop, which goes against the best practise. Is there any way to overcome that?

Comment: It's not best practice to run queries in a loop _when they can be bulkified_. However, since you cannot bulkify these queries beyond batching in 20s, it is the required implementation pattern - unless you can reduce the scope of data you need to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's governor limit and not possible to by-pass.

But `getRelationshipName`() returns all the childs including **standards** ones like

> Events,ProcessInstances,Processsteps,Feeds, Topics,
>   RecordActionHistories and list goes on

. Actually you might not need most of them. I would suggest you to review the child which is been received form the getRelationshipName and then include only the necessary ones.

You can also store the necessary child names the `static variable or a custom label`

and check before adding them to the query.

Hope this helps!!